# Accessing header container in Extjs4

Tags: extjs

I want to call the `getGridColumns()` method of the header container but I am not getting access to the grid's header container. I tried the following:

```
initComponent : function() {
            var grid = this;

    var headerCt = grid.getView.getHeaderCt(); //here
    var menuItems = new Array();
    menuItems = headerCt.getGridColumns(true);
               ...
}
```

but this is not working. It gives me error as 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. Any suggestions?

Comment: just a quick thought: var headerCt = grid.getView().getHeaderCt(); you missed () in getView

Comment: @bhakti waghmare I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to satisfy most of my needs to access a grids header container by setting listeners when defining the columns of the grid (by passing in an object instead of just an array). Then, set your array of columns in the items of the columns object. 
Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  ...,
  columns : {
    listeners : {
      boxready : function(headerCt) {
        console.log(headerCt);
      }
    },
    items : []
  },
  ...
});
```

Once you have the `headerCt` then you can call `getGridColumns()` or `getVisibleGridColumns()`.
Hope this helps.